# Mysql select query to find a value in certain range

Tags: mysql, select-query

I have a items table,

```
id    item    min_price   max_price
-----------------------------------
1     item1    100         500
2     item2    150         400
3     item3    410         700
4     item4    330         700
5     item3    420         600
```

When I pass the price value `450`, I expect a result with 450 containing range values, ie,

```
 id    item    min_price   max_price
-----------------------------------

3     item3    410         700
5     item3    420         600
```

How do I get this result ?

I tried this query,

```
SELECT * FROM items where min_price >= 450 AND max_price <= 450
```

But no result. How to get the correct result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed them up:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE min_price <= 450 
  AND max_price >= 450
```

You can always use `between` which will help you to avoid this problems in the future:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE 450 between min_price and max_price
```